# Working with strings in Python: Formatting the information in a very specific way

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

OBS: I am working on Python 3.5.2 and I use the standard Shell and IDLE

Hi everyone, I think one of the most difficult tasks I have when programming with python is dealing with strings. Is there someone who can help?

One of the problems I face frequently is transforming the string so I can use it properly. For instance:

```
#consider I have the following string I want to work with:
```

**`my_input = 'insert 3 ["psyduck", 30]!!!insert 10 ["a nice day at the beach", 100]!!!find 3!!!find 10'`**

How can I transform this string in a  way that, with the results, I would be able to do the following:

*1 - Separate the following substrings into variables like this:*

```
command = 'insert'

node = '3' #or the int 3

list = '["psyduck", 30]'
```

*2 - Or any other solution that will somehow enable me to do this in the end:*

```
listOfCommands = [['insert', '3', '["psyduck", 30]'], ['insert', '10', '["a nice day at the beach", 100]'], ['find', '3'], ['find', '10']]
```

I need this list in order to do the following:

```
for entry in listOfCommands:
    if entry[0] == 'insert':
    #I will execute a part of the program    

    elif entry[0] == 'update':
    #execute something else

    elif entry[0] == 'find':
    #execute something else
```

The problem is that I do not know exaclty what is going to appear (the number of commands or the size of the information I will have to add) in the input. I just know that it will always obey these exact formats: 
**[A command, a 'node' where I have to store the information or update it, the information I have to store or update]** or **[A command, a 'node' I have to find or delete]** and the blocks will be separated by '!!!'

I can work my way around the main program but in order to be able to make it run properly, I need to have this input formatted in this really specific way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work:

```
commands = my_input.split('!!!')
my_commands = [c.split(' ', 2) for c in commands]
```

The second argument of the `split` methods tells it how many times you want it to split the string.

Comment: Yeah, depending on the complexity of the input, this little hack might just work.

Comment: To get a list, you can always `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't get into parsing the third argument since it's a job of the corresponding command, but most probably either `json` or `ast.literal_eval` will work.